# Converging function with dense pole set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let
$$f: \mathbb C^\times \to \mathbb R, \quad f(z):=
\begin{cases}\log(|z|),\quad&|z|<1,\\
0, &|z| \ge 1,
\end{cases},
$$
and $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers with
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = 1$$
and $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence running injectively through all elements of $Q:=\{ 
x+iy \in \mathbb C : x,y \in \mathbb Q \}$. We consider the function
$$g: \mathbb C \setminus Q \to \mathbb R, \quad g(z):= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n f(z-q_n).$$

**My question:** At which points does $g$ converge? Does this depend on the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(q_n)$? Can they be chosen in such a way that $g$ converges everywhere?

**Background:**
By Fubini–Tonelli we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} g(x+iy) dx dy = \int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x+iy) dx dy = - \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
So $g$ converges almost everywhere. This is hard to imagine since you would imagine the limit to have poles on the dense subset $Q$.

Well, the solution of this alleged contradiction will be that the limit won't be continuous (even though $f$ is). So we can't really talk about poles.