# Converging function with dense set of singularities

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, logarithms, pointwise-convergence, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Since my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300038/converging-function-with-dense-pole-set) seems to be too complicated (since even though I put a bounty on it nobody answered or commented) I want to break it down a little bit. Maybe it gets answerable by reducing it by a dimension and making already the choices.

Let
$$f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R\cup\{-\infty\}, \quad f(x):=
\begin{cases}\log(|x|),\quad&|x|<1,\\
0, &|x| \ge 1,
\end{cases},
$$

so $f(x)=\min(0,\log(|x|))$. With $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ we run through all rational numbers in $(0,1]$ in the following order:
$$1,\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{2}{3},\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{3}{4},\tfrac{1}{5},\tfrac{2}{5},\tfrac{3}{5},\dots$$

We consider the function
$$g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\cup\{-\infty\}, \quad g(x):= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{f(x-q_n)}{2^n}.$$

**My question:** At which $x \in [0,1]$ do we have $g(x)=-\infty$? Only on the points in $\mathbb Q \cap (0,1]$?

**Background:**
By Fubini–Tonelli we have
$$\int_{\mathbb R} g(x) dx = \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \frac{-2}{2^n} = -2.$$
So $|g(x)|< \infty$ almost everywhere. This is hard to imagine.

Comment: @postmortes I mean the minimum (it should agree then with the other definition) and I define $\log(0)=-\infty$ to make $\log(|x|)$ continuous at $0$.

Comment: I don't have the details filled in, but basically for irrational $x, g(x)$ is finite for the same reason that $\int_0^1\ln t\,dt$ is finite. Yes, there are infinitely many $n$ for which $f(x - q_n)$ is below any given bound. But the density of such $n$ drops off fast enough that growth is much less than $2^n$, leaving $g(x)$ finite.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I don't believe that before seeing details ;-). For example it is possible to find a sequence of open subsets of $\mathbb R$ with $O_1 \supset O_2 \supset O_3 \dots$ such that the intersection of all of them is of measure $0$ and still contains $\mathbb Q$. But in those cases the intersection always contains in addition uncountable many irrationals. It's not possible to have it equals $\mathbb Q$ by the Baire category theorem.

Comment: I do not blame you for being unconvinced. I was only throwing out the idea, not making any real argument for it (thus a comment, not an answer). Though you already made an argument in the post that something like this must be true. However I do not find your Baire category example apropo to this situation. The summation defining $g$ only involves rational translates of a single value. The existence of uncountable other nearby values that are not included in the sum seems immaterial to me.